# Finding the limit of an alternating sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have the limit of an alternating sequence:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (-1)^n \frac{3^{2n+1}n^{2n}}{(4n-1)^{2n}}$$

I understand that if the limit of the absolute value of the sequence is $0$, then the sequence is convergent.

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{3^{2n+1}n^{2n}}{(4n-1)^{2n}}$$

But I don't know how to approach this limits, or what techniques to use.

Comment: Sequence or series.  If the limit of absolute value of the sequence is $0$ then the limit of the sequence is $0$.

Comment: We know that for any real number that $-|x| \le x \le |x|$.  So for any sequence $-|a_n| \le a_n \le |a_n|$.   So if we know $|a_n| \to 0$ then we know $-|a_n| \to 0$ and by the squeeze theorem $a_n \to 0$

Comment: Wait... Is your question how do we know $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{3^{2n+1}n^{2n}}{(4n-1)^{2n}}=0 $?  Or is it about if we know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{3^{2n+1}n^{2n}}{(4n-1)^{2n}} = 0$ how do we know what $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (-1)^n \frac{3^{2n+1}n^{2n}}{(4n-1)^{2n}}$ is?  or is it what is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{3^{2n+1}n^{2n}}{(4n-1)^{2n}}$?  Or is it something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that we can write

$$\frac{3^{2n+1}n^{2n}}{(4n-1)^{2n}}=3\left(\frac{3n}{4n-1}\right)^{2n}=3\left(\frac{3/4}{1-\frac1{4n}}\right)^{2n}$$

Can you conclude now?

Comment: Yes this helps out a lot, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.